# Display column from one list on NewForm of other list

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, spservices, newform

In ListA there are two columns, **Title** and **Due Date**, while in the other ListB there are several columns, one of those named **Milestone** is a lookup on **Title** column of ListA.
In NewForm of ListB I have dropdown/choice field **Milestone** and based on what user chooses I want to display **Due date** (just readable).

Any suggestion how is this achievable? Maybe I can do this using javascript or SPServices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go CSR, but there is an oldskool 2007 way that is still valid

Add a **hidden** ListView of List A on your New Form, that is the easiest way to read ListA data without using JSOM or REST

Then below your Form add a CEWP with Javascript code:

- attach an eventListner on the dropdown
- on triggered, get the data from List A
  in `ctx.ListData.Row`, *no need to leech the DOM as in old 2007 days*

This code should get you started.. no jQuery, no SPServices, no SPUtility required

In a CEWP **below** the New Form, and that ListView at the top (hide it after your code works)

I did it with a standard **Status** dropdown...

```
//id contains Status , ends with DropDowChoice
var dropdown=document.querySelector("[id*='Status'][id$='DropDownChoice']");
dropdown.addEventListener('change',function(){
    var matcheditem=ctx.ListData.Row.find(function(item){
        console.log('checking Item',dropdown.value,item);
        return item.Status === dropdown.value;   //replace with item.Title
    });
    if(matcheditem.length){
        console.log('matched Item',matcheditem);
        var oneMatchid='matchedStatus';// unique ID for bookkeeping
        var matchedSPAN=document.querySelector("#"+oneMatchid); //find if SPAN exists
        var matchedHTML=matchedSPAN ? matchedSPAN : document.createElement('SPAN');
        matchedHTML.id=oneMatchid;
        matchedHTML.innerHTML=matcheditem.Title;//add matched value below dropdown
        var TD=dropdown.parentNode.parentNode;
        if(!matchedSPAN) TD.appendChild(matchedHTML);    //only add once
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this today and get back to say how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Beside great post by Danny I found another solution with help of jquery.
Firstly I created cascading drop downs in ListB.

I made two lookup columns in ListB, Milestone and DueDate from ListB. So, both columns are visible on custom NewForm.

After this I created cascade drop downs so when user chooses Mileston, DueDate column is filtered.

Than I came across on new challenge. Default value for DueDate was None, but first/only option when clicked on drop down was DueDate of that Milestone.
So it meant I have to display a value of DueDate not None word.

I wrote a function to get first child of drop down and to display that value in additional td I created in NewForm next to td where drop down is. I hid drop down and was left with the label, as I wanted.

After this I came up a new problem, as value of DueDate that was displayed on label was in ISO format, not in format I wanted DD.MM.YYYY, that meant I have to write a new function for Date and Time convert.

After that, I got readable Date value as I needed.